# Is it possible to build indexes with included columns in laravel (SQL server like)

Tags: laravel, indexing, include

In SQL server it is possible to build indexes including columns, like this:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_cust_email_inc
ON sales.customers(email)
INCLUDE(first_name,last_name);
```

It is possible do something like this in a migration on Laravel?

At the moment, I can create an index like this, as you see this not have `INCLUDE` functionality:

```
$table->index(['email']);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer for Laravel 8.x is you can, but not using any Laravel tool. You simply need to run the code as raw sqlserver query.

The code should look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MyMigration extends Migration{
    public function up(){
        if(config('database.default')=="sqlsrv"){
            DB::statement("CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name_1,column_name_1) INCLUDE (column_name_3, column_name_4);");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the index usage by laravel https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#creating-indexes, and here the way to execute raw sql code https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#running-queries